# `echo test?` prints `test2` but `ls test?` prints nothing

Tags: shell, ls

I was playing with bash globbing recently and I noticed the following:

First, make 2 dirs:

```
$ mkdir test
$ mkdir test2
```

Then:

```
$ echo test?
```

Outputs (correctly):

```
test2
```

But:

```
$ ls test?
```

Outputs nothing ...

But, if you make one more directory (test3), `echo` and `ls` work as supposed.

Does anyone has any idea why this happens?

Comment: Yes.  You've just made `test2`.  It's empty.  `ls` of a single empty directory should return nothing.  It does.  If you have more than one argument to `ls`, it helpfully outputs a disambiguation line telling you which empty directory it's listing now, which is why you get output in the `test3` case; but with only one argument, such disambiguation isn't needed, so you don't get it.

Comment: To add to @MadHatter, `ls -d directory` lists the directory name itself, otherwise `ls directory` lists the contents of that directory.

Comment: `touch test2/wut ; ls test?`

Comment: Makes sense, I noticed it today :) Question closed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try and understand from basic.

```
mkdir test
touch file
mkdir test1
mkdir test2
```

The `?` searches for one, and only one, character.

Now, when we issue the command `ls tes?` the output would be, `file`.

It worked because we created a file inside the directory. From man page of `ls`,

```
NAME
       ls - list directory contents
```

The directory `test` has the `file` inside and so the `ls` command actually lists the files that is present inside the directory.

Now, let us create a file as below.

```
touch ramesh
ls rames?
ramesh
```

The reason the above command worked is because `ramesh` is a file and it is present under the current directory (As per the `ls` working, it lists directory contents and in the current directory there is actually  a file named `ramesh`).

Now, let us create a directory named `ram1` as below.

```
mkdir ram1
ls ram?
```

The above outputs nothing. It is because `ram1` directory currently has no files inside it. Now, if we create another directory named `ram2` and try, it works because it first checks if `ram1` directory has any files and then checks if `ram2` directory has any files. Remember `ls` works on sorting.

If you want to see more on the internal working, issue the `stat` command.

In this case, `stat ram?` would produce the output as,

```
  File: `ram1'
  Size: 4096            Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 805h/2053d      Inode: 6743976     Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
Access: 2014-06-30 18:17:06.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2014-06-30 18:17:03.000000000 -0500
Change: 2014-06-30 18:17:03.000000000 -0500
```